# Unable to ping Computers connected to two different Access Points of the same router

Tags: router, wireless-router, lan, ping, wireless-access-point

I have a D-Link wireless router with four ethernet ports. I have two Wireless Access Points enabled on my router. If I connect say PC1 and PC2 to two of the ethernet ports it can ping each other. If connect both PC1 and PC2 to AP1 it can ping each other. Similarly when I connect both to AP2 it can ping each other. But If I connect PC1 and PC2 on two different APs or one to an AP and other to ethernet then It cant ping each other.

The IP of Router = 192.168.1.1

The IP of PC1 = 192.168.1.2

The IP of PC2 = 192.168.1.5

They are static IP addresses

I have unchecked "Configure the second IP Address and Subnet Mask for LAN" which comes under Local Network settings in the router and I have turned the setting "User Isolation" to "off" for both the Wireless Access Points. But still the problem persists. What is the reason? How can I solve this problem so that I can ping all the PCs which is connected to other APs or ethernet of the same router?

Comment: It might be an idea to try the reverse.... set your router so that it is a DHCP server, reset your APs and make sure they are configured with IPs outside your DHCP scope, the same subnet and point to DHCP server as gateway. Set your devices to obtain IPs automatically and then test your scenarios. If they all work then you can simply disable the DHCP server and set your clients to have their static IPs and point to router as gateway...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have buggy/broken "From DS" multicast on your wireless networks and it's breaking ARP broadcasts.

Try entering static ARP mappings for PC1 on PC2 and for PC2 on PC1.

If that fixes it, troubleshoot your multicast situation. Delete the static ARP mappings and reproduce the problem. Then disable wireless security temporarily and see if the problem goes away. If it does, try WPA2-ONLY mode (make sure original WPA/TKIP is not enabled in any way).

Setting your multicast rate too high can also break multicast. Try setting it to the lowest setting.